# api-platform: Filter on collection with embedded objects does not work

Tags: filter, api-platform.com

Im using Api-Platform v2.5.10 and have embedded privilege-objects.
If I try to filter for a value (customID) I also get other objects, that have the same privilege (embedded) but other value for customID.

My tables:

```
objects
    customID | privilegeID
    ---------+-----------
    123456   | marketing
    123456   | design
    9876543  | marketing

privileges
    privilegeID | name
    ------------+-----------
    marketing   | Marketing Chef
    design      | Just gimp
```

if I now call /objects?customID=9876543 I get 9876543 AND 123456 as a reply, because they both have "marketing" as privilege

```
{
  "customID": "9876543",
  "privilege": {
        "privilegeID": "marketing",
        "name": "Marketing Chef"
  }
},
{
  "customID": "123456",
  "privilege": {
        "privilegeID": "marketing",
        "name": "Marketing Chef"
  }
}
```

If I remove the groups annotation ("object:read"), I get the result as expected, but without the embedded privilege-object

```
@Groups({"privileg:read", "privileg:write", "object:read"})
```

Seems like Api-Platform does not build a correct SQL-Statement as it looks kind of

```
SELECT g0_.custom_id    AS custom_id_0,
       p1_.privilege_id AS privilege_id_2,
       p1_.name         AS name_3,
       g0_.privilege    AS privilege_4
FROM object g0_
         LEFT JOIN privilege p1_ ON g0_.privilege = p1_.privilege_id
WHERE g0_.privilege IN (SELECT g2_.privilege AS sclr_14
                        FROM object g2_
                                 LEFT JOIN privilege p3_ ON g2_.privilege = p3_.privilege_id
                        WHERE g2_.custom_id = '9876543')
ORDER BY g0_.custom_id ASC, g0_.privilege ASC;
```

Problem here is the "WHERE g0_.privilege IN (", as this get ALL  objects with the privileges from the filtered object.

Any ideas?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

As we found the same issue on Github:
https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3214

The solution there worked fine. We had just to add

```
 * @ApiResource(
 *     ...
 *     attributes={"force_eager"=false}
 * )
```

Seems to be a problem with composite keys and embedded objects. Force_Eager=FALSE splits the SQL-Statements.

```
SELECT u0_.custom_id AS custom_id_0, u0_.privilege AS privilege_1
FROM user u0_
WHERE u0_.custom_id = '9876543'
ORDER BY u0_.custom_id ASC, u0_.privilege ASC
LIMIT 30;

SELECT t0.name_id AS name_id_1, t0.name AS name_2
FROM privilege t0
WHERE t0.name_id = 'design';

SELECT COUNT(*) AS dctrn_count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT custom_id_0, privilege_1
      FROM (SELECT u0_.custom_id AS custom_id_0, u0_.privilege AS privilege_1
            FROM user u0_
            WHERE u0_.custom_id = '9876543'
            ORDER BY u0_.custom_id ASC, u0_.privilege ASC) dctrn_result) dctrn_table;
```

BTW: I renamed Object with User to get rid of a PHP conflict :-)